# Chained attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

Is there a way to make a python class such that,

```py
a = Foo()
a.user.details.money.pay = 130000
print(a.user.details.money.pay)
```

outputs 130000

If possible, could you also explain the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python calls `__getattr__` when it can't find an attribute on an object. Your class could use that to assign a new instance of itself to the attribute. Now you have a named attribute that will play the same game for the next attribute down the line.

```
class Foo:

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        setattr(self, name, foo:=Foo())
        return foo


a = Foo()
a.user.details.money.pay = 130000
print(a.user.details.money.pay)
```

Here, `a.__getattr__` creates `user`, `a.user.__getattr__` creates `details`, and etc. Since this is an assignment operation, that last component, `pay`, is a `__setattr__` operation, not a `__getattr__`, so your custom getter doesn't run.

This can mask bugs as this class will create unintended attributes as well.